Type mismatch: inferred type is Context but BinaryMessenger was expected (Flutter)
I am using "sms_advanced" package in flutter in which I want to get the list of all the sms which is on user's device.
I want to capture transaction notifications from SMS messages on the user’s device, that's why I have set up a mechanism to read notifications or incoming SMS messages.
Add Permissions in AndroidManifest.xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>

Request Runtime Permissions
dependencies:
  permission_handler: ^11.3.1

Flutter code to request SMS permissions
Future<void> requestSmsPermission() async {
    var status = await Permission.sms.status;
    if (!status.isGranted) {
      var result = await Permission.sms.request();
      if (result.isDenied || result.isPermanentlyDenied) {
        // Handle denied permissions if needed
        debugPrint("SMS permission denied.");
      }
    }
  }

"MainActivity.kt" file
package com.example.expense_tracker

import android.os.Bundle
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel

class MainActivity : FlutterFragmentActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "com.example.expense_tracker/notifications"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        MethodChannel(flutterEngine?.dartExecutor?.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            if (call.method == "startNotificationListener") {
                startNotificationListener()
                result.success(null)
            } else {
                result.notImplemented()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun startNotificationListener() {
        // Your code to start listening for notifications
        // e.g., start a BroadcastReceiver for SMS notifications
    }
}

Implement SMS BroadcastReceiver
package com.example.expense_tracker

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.telephony.SmsMessage
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel

class SmsReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (intent.action == "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED") {
            val bundle: Bundle? = intent.extras
            val pdus = bundle?.get("pdus") as? Array<*>
            pdus?.forEach { pdu ->
                val smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu(pdu as ByteArray)
                val messageBody = smsMessage.messageBody

                // Check if messageBody contains transaction information
                if (messageBody.contains("transaction")) {
                    // Send data back to Flutter
                    MethodChannel(context, "com.example.expense_tracker/notifications")
                        .invokeMethod("notifyTransaction", messageBody)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Register the BroadcastReceiver in AndroidManifest.xml
<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Flutter code to start Notification Listener
Future<void> _startNotificationListener() async {
    try {
      await platform.invokeMethod('startNotificationListener');
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      debugPrint("e.message: ${e.message}");
    }
  }

After doing all of this it is showing the error "Type mismatch: inferred type is Context but BinaryMessenger was expected"
Screenshot
When I am running my app using the command "flutter run" then it is showing the error my app is not even building, Here's the screenshot:
